# How to read triangles and vertices of the model from the STL format?

Tags: javascript, three.js, stl-format

I need to get information about the vertices and triangles of the STL format model, please tell me how to extract this data in ThreeJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `STLLoader` class for this task. So you define an instance of the loader and use it to load a STL asset from a specific path. In the `onLoad()` callback, you get an instance of `BufferGeometry` representing the geometry data from the STL file.

```js
const loader = new STLLoader();
loader.load( './models/stl/ascii/slotted_disk.stl', function ( geometry ) {

    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    scene.add( mesh );

} );
```

Keep in mind that the geometry is non-indexed. So the faces/triangles are defined by three consecutive vertices in the `position` buffer attribute.

Full example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_stl